# Finding $\frac{890×12.34×0.0637}{87.35×2.274}$ using logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

> Find $\dfrac{890×12.34×0.0637}{87.35×2.274}$ by using logarithms.

$$\log(890)=2.9494,\ \log(12.34)=1.0913,\ \log(0.0637)=-2.8041,\\\log(87.35)=1.9412,\ \log(2.274)=0.3568,$$
therefore the calculation becomes
$$(2.9494+1.0913-2.8041)-(1.9412+0.3568)=-1.0614\\\log^{-1}(-1.0614)\approx0.1152.$$
But this is the wrong answer because just plugging in the original numbers in a calculator gets $3.522$. I can't see where I made a mistake. Thanks.

Comment: $\log \left( 0.0637 \right)$ is wrong ^^

Comment: Yes I see log(0.0637) = -1.1959. My original value was from the log tables. But there's confusion about the negative characteristic. For example in the problem 14.68 x 0.2685, the respective logarithms are 1.1668 and -1.4289 (from log tables, or -0.571 from calculator), yet if I do 1.1668 + (-1.4289) I get the correct answer, whereas using (-0.571) I get a wrong answer. This contradicts why in this current problem log(0.0637) = -1.1959 and not -2.8041 from the log tables.

Comment: $\log_{10}(0.0637)=-1.19586$ but $\log_{e}(0.0637)=-2.75357$

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that you use a table, when you look at the value for $0.0637$, we viewed it as $6.37\times 10^{-2}$.

Taking logarithm, we have $$-2 + \log(6.37)=-2\color{red}+0.8041=-1.1959$$