# Basic logarithm calculation negative characteristic confusion

Tags: logarithms, arithmetic

I'm very confused about logarithm calculations. Here's an eaxmple: $890\times12.34\times0.0637=?$

All these are logs with base 10. The following logs were found from the log tables.

$log(890)=2.9494,\space log(12.34)=1.0913, \space log(0.0637)=\overline{2}.8041$

This is my calculation by hand:

$\begin{array}{r}
&2.9494\\
+&1.0913\\&\bar{2}.8041\\\hline &2.8448
\end{array}
$

$log^{-1}(2.8448) \approx 699.6 \space $

Which is the correct answer.

Yet just plugging into a calculator you get something else:

$2.9494+1.0913+(-2.8041)=1.2366 \\ log^{-1}(1.2366)\approx17.24$

Obviously this is wrong.

Why? I'm very confused about what's going on. I know it has something to do with the negative characteristic but can't see how.

Comment: $\bar{2}.8041 = -2+0.8041.$

Comment: $\log_{10}(0.0637)$ is not $-2.8041$

Comment: also, this question looks very similar to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3670696/finding-frac890%C3%9712-34%C3%970-063787-35%C3%972-274-using-logarithms

Comment: i know $\bar{2}.8041 = -2+0.8041$ so how come when I write it out and add it all up by hand I can work with -2.8041 (and not write -1.1959) but when I input it into the calculator it has to be -1.1959?